# Как передать макросы в параметры компилятора cmake

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, макросы

Как передать макросы в параметры компилятора, используя cmake?

Comment: [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) или это не то?

Comment: [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html)